# react rnd - marker position changes on screen size change

Tags: css, html, image, reactjs, position

I am displaying an image and then using a marker on it.
the problem is that when the screen size is altered. the marker also changes its position, why is this happening? and how can I fix this so that the marker stays on the same position relative to the image.
here's the link -> https://codesandbox.io/s/34x4lrovmm

Comment: Have you tried to replicate the issue without using react-rnd?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I am doing now. i started to use react-draggable now to achieve the same functionality. looking better,  but I hope I am able to achieve the functionality I want with this.

Comment: @faraz Hi, I am also facing the same issues with react-draggable for position changing of markers on parent div or window size alteration. Can you please paste your solution here.. it will be helpful and save my days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are many ways to do that here's one of them.

You need just to set static `width` and `height` for image

[image]

Comment: i tried and although it does help a bit, but the position still changes when the window size changes a lot.

Comment: Please make sure to avoid using maxWidth and maxHeight with percent value use pixels instead because it will ruin the position https://codesandbox.io/s/40ov0j0l80

Comment: okay, yes. that makes sense.
just one more problem. when I zoom. the marker changes to a different position. you know how to adjust so, it comes to same position when we zoomin or zoomout?

Comment: I'm not seeing any problem while zooming https://giphy.com/gifs/yc2MoPe1y3HRlZZ9IY/fullscreen

Comment: Ooh now I saw your updates on Codesandbox you aren't zooming correctly you're just changing the width and height of the image and that will ruin the position because of the marker doesn't responsive with the image. Image width and height shouldn't be changeable

Comment: If you want to do a zoom here's the correct way https://codesandbox.io/s/40ov0j0l80 this zoom will implement only for zoom and marker

Comment: yeah. it is working. but looking at the code i didnt understand. how exactly the zoom is happening. it seems like zoom is a css property here